# Extract Image From The Web to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to extract an image from a website I subscribe to which produces graphs that are updated daily.

My code uses `querySelector` and `getAttribute` to extract the graph I want imported into Excel.

The problem is that my code can't get the src address. I believe my html references are correct.

The html source:

```
<img class="chart-img" style="max-height: 150px;" alt="Chart ID 2669" 
 src="https://website.com/c/422/charts/ClearChart_2054_128978589342.jpg" diagnostic- 
 id="chart-img-1" chart-id="2669">`
```

My current code

```
Sub ImportImage()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Dim HTMLImg As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    
    strURL = "https://website.com/chartbooks/22920"
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate strURL
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 '4 = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set HTMLDoc = .document
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set HTMLImg = HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[alt='Chart ID 2669']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        If Not HTMLImg Is Nothing Then
            .Picture = HTMLImg.getAttribute("src")
        Else
            .Value = "Image not found"
        End If
    End With
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set HTMLImg = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the image into the sheet, not the cell. After you insert the image into the sheet, you can have additional code to manipulate the position and size of the image.

Try the code below.

```
Sub ImportImage()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Dim HTMLImg As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    
    strURL = "https://website.com/chartbooks/22920"
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True ' do you really need IE visible ?
        .navigate strURL
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 '4 = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set HTMLDoc = .document
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next        
 
    Set HTMLImg = HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[alt='Chart ID 2669']")
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If Not HTMLImg Is Nothing Then
            ' Insert the picture into the sheet, not the cell
            .Pictures.Insert (HTMLImg.getAttribute("src"))
        Else
            .Range("A1").Value = "Image not found"
        End If
    End With
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set HTMLImg = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and input your explanation makes sense, but unfortunately I'm still getting "Image Not Found"

Comment: Because The URL in your code do not have the image with (alt="Chart ID 2669"), I though it was behind a paywall that is why I personally could not reach it. But the code I gave above does work. You can test it with a URL that you are sure has an image. e.g. I tested it with https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page and query **("img[alt='ET Afar asv2018-01 img58 Dallol.jpg']")**

Comment: I see now what you mean. Yes, my problem is the way the website is set up. Its set up so after you log in the site directs you to a webpage, the webpage referenced is the URL  provided, that looks similar to how power point presentations are set up. I wanted to reference a particular "slide" with the graph, but like you said the url code must not have the image. All of that probably makes no sense, but I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @a_js12 as this answer will work for web pages that are accessible (i.e. your outstanding problem is that it is the "https://website.com/chartbooks/22920" URL that prevents access), you should probably mark this as accepted answer as per [the SO Guidelines - "Decide if the answer is helpful, and then..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).